Draw lines between several points with known coordinates
My task: to connect points with lines using known coordinates.
What I have already done: using the doctr library, I find the coordinates of the words I am interested in on a pdf file. (My python code is not important for this question, below I will show what data I get from a specific file)
For example, there is a pdf file in which I am looking for the word "INVOICE"

After doctr has run, I get the following data
((0.09370404411764705, 0.0439453125), (0.33140099789915967, 0.09765625));
((0.5925912552521009, 0.1796875), (0.6575433298319328, 0.1953125));
((0.5925912552521009, 0.2041015625), (0.6575433298319328, 0.21875));
My question: how can I draw lines between these three points? To get a figure at the output.
For a better understanding of the situation for you: the figure on this file will be like a template for me. I receive a large number of documents, and in order not to look through everything, I will check whether this figure is on the received document, and look through only the necessary document.

Where is point (0.0937,0.043) located? What are the units?

How is this related to matplotlib?

@MarkSetchell Thank you for paying attention to my question. As I understood from the documentation, I get the result as xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

@MarkSetchell If you know how to solve this problem without matplotlib, I will be happy to read your options. Just before asking the question, I studied similar solutions to problems and almost everywhere used this library

@KJ Thank you for the explanation. But tell me what I need to do with the data (0.09370404411764705, 0.0439453125) to display it correctly on the axis. How can I transform this data to get the correct point on the coordinate axis?

@KJ I believe you are really good at understanding many aspects. Maybe you can help me figure out the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78670888/17122431

You can use PyMuPDF Library. The following code snippet will help you.
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("Document_Name_Original.pdf")
page = doc[pno]  # page number
p1 = fitz.Point(x_1, y_1)  # First point
p2 = fitz.Point(x_2, y_2)  # Second point
p3 = fitz.Point(x_3, y_3)  # Third point
page.draw_line(p1, p2, color=fitz.pdfcolor["red"], width=2)
page.draw_line(p2, p3, color=fitz.pdfcolor["red"], width=2)
page.draw_line(p3, p1, color=fitz.pdfcolor["red"], width=2)
doc.save("Document_Name_Modified.pdf")

Through this library, you can modify, add graph and add any plotting. If you want to know detail, this link 1 and link 2 help you for guide drawing on PDF document.

Links only don't make good answers. If you want to give links leave them as comments...

Okay I will expose my answer

@Yavuz BALI Thanks for the answer. The thing is that I don't get any figure in the resulting file. Maybe fitz requires a different format for coordinates (not decimal numbers, but integers). I'll experiment now

I achieved solution and get figured. May be would be you forget to assignment page number (variable pno) or there are scale problem  on coordinate base. Because pymupdf get as (0,0) point at page left corner. May be we need scale up to doctr library output

@Yavuz BALI
As for the page number, so far I always have one page. But with scaling... good idea, I'll check it now
