Why is the zero point of the coordinate system (0, 0) for the pymupdf library sometimes start from the upper right corner?
Using the doctr library, I recognize text on a PDF file. From the entire text, I select keywords and the coordinates of these words. I receive the coordinates in the following format:
list_with_coordinates = [(0.09370404411764705, 0.0439453125), (0.5925912552521009, 0.1796875), (0.5925912552521009, 0.2041015625)]

Next, I transform these coordinates to get real points (to plot the points on the coordinate system). I do this using the Fitz library.
import fitz
from pymupdf import Point   

doc = fitz.open("file_name.pdf")
page = doc[0]

list_with_points = []
for i in list_with_coordinates:
    list_with_points.append(fitz.Point([i[0] * page.rect.width, i[1] * page.rect.height]))

Next, I draw lines from point to point.
for i in range(len(list_with_points) - 1):
    page.draw_line(list_with_points[i], list_with_points[i+1])

And at this point, I have a question: the zero point of the coordinate system (0, 0) for the Fitz library is in the top left corner. And for most documents, this rule works (that is, I connect the words I need with lines). However, there are cases when, in some documents, the zero point of the coordinate system (0, 0) starts from the top right corner. And I have not found any information about this anywhere.
Please tell me why this happens, and how can I fix it?

@KJ Thanks for the explanation. But tell me, how can I control this? That is:

how can I understand which reference point the PDF uses?
how can I convert coordinates from one reference point to another


The (Py)MuPDF library supports more than a dozen of different document types. PDF is just one out the many. Images are supported as document types as well! (In addition to being also native images). So the decision was made (in MuPDF) a long time ago to use top-left as (0, 0). PDF uses bottom-left as (0, 0). Which is more intuitive in terms of the positive y-direction is upwards. But this means you need to know the page height if you want to address a location on a page. And even PDF addresses images from top-left to bottom-right.

For coordinate conversion, there exist several easy-to-use transformation means. E.g. if you have a point = Point(x, y) in PDF coordinates, the PyMuPDF coordinates of that point are point * page.transformation_matrix. PyMuPDF supports all algebraic operations of its geometry objects by standard Python operators. For the inverse computation, PyMuPDF => PDF, do point * ~page.transformation_matrix, where the ~ operator creates the inverse of a matrix. Please also consult this docu section.

@JorjMcKie Thank you for such a detailed answer. I learned a lot. But the question is a little different: I come across problematic documents in which the origin point (0,0) is not in the upper left corner (as is usually the case), but in the upper right (for unknown reasons). How can I specify for this problematic document that the reference point starts from the upper left corner?

A page may be rotated (90° multiples). This can be determined by Page.rotation. If e.g. this is 90, then the page has its origin at top-right. To do your line draws, you must transform all coordinates by multiplying them with the appropriate matrix. Or remove the page's rotation (Page.remove_rotation()) . This leads to permanently changing the page's coordinate system, such that (0,0) is again top-left and you can work as usual.

@JorjMcKie Thank you very much. Your advice really helped me. If you wish, you can mark this as an answer and I will mark it.
